# Types plugin custom post add_action hooks

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, actions

I'm using the wp-types plugin to create a custom post type. I'm developing my own plugin which I need to fire whenever a post of my custom post type is updated.

Right now `add_action( 'save_post', 'myFunc');` will fire if a regular post is updated, however not if one of of the custom posts is updated.

Does anyone know why this might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
    add_action( 'save_post', 'myFunc');
function myFunc(){
if ($post->post_type == 'cpt' ) {
// do action here
}
```

OR

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'myFunc');
function myFunc(){
if ( 'cpt' == get_post_type() ) {
// do action here
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151409/wordpress-save-post-action-for-custom-posts]

Comment: save_post should work for custom post types also. Can you paste the code you are writing for the save_post callback ?

Comment: Check this link I think it's useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56785987/creating-the-single-and-functions-page-for-custom-plugin